# Unable To Communicate With The Server Error In A List in SharePoint On Premises

Tags: internal-server-error

While quick editing, a user gets an error which is shown in the image below. It works for the other users. Has anyone ran into a problem like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What’s the permission of the user in this list and site? Make sure the user has at least Edit permission in this list and have permission at the site level.

How many items you paste simultaneously in this list? Please make sure you paste less than 100 items at a time.

Comment: The user has permisions both on the list and at the site level, we`ve also made a mistake its on premise not online. There is also less than a 100 items in the list

Answer (score 0):

this error happens, when a user edits items in Classic Experience style & quick edit mode.
Solution for me - go to Modern Experience style (left bottom corner).
(only for Sharepoint Online/SPO & 2016 onPrem)